# Session selection menu in Tmux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tmux

I have a script .bashrc autorun tmux when connected via ssh, which automatically connects me to the previous session:

```
if [ "$PS1" != "" -a "${STARTED_TMUX:-x}" = x -a "${SSH_TTY:-x}" != x ]
then
        STARTED_TMUX=1; export STARTED_TMUX
        sleep 1
        ( (tmux has-session -t remote && tmux attach-session -t remote) || (tmux new-session -s remote) ) && exit 0
        echo "tmux failed to start"
fi
```

How can I supplement this script so that it offers to start a new session or connect to an existing session with each new connection? As a selection menu.

I would like to have a simple menu for connecting to an existing session (or sessions) or creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`select` built-in](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_06.html):

```bash
tmuxSelectSession() {
    PS3='Select a tmux session to attach to: '
    select session in $(tmux list-sessions -F "#{session_name}"); do
        tmux attach -t "$session"
        break
    done
}

tmuxHasSessions() {
    tmux list-sessions 2>&1 >/dev/null
}

isTmuxSession() {
    test -n "$TMUX"
}

if ! isTmuxSession; then
    tmuxHasSessions && tmuxSelectSession || tmux new-session -s new
fi
```

Comment: I understand correctly, it is enough to add your script to .bashrc?

Comment: @Neliker, not in its current form. If you want to include it directly into the .bashrc, you can  do something like this: `if ! isTmuxSession; then tmuxHasSessions && tmuxSelectSession || tmux; fi`. I've updated the answer.